# Pergunta negativada e marcada para fechar

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento

Fala pessoal!

Sobre essa questão:
[Remover barra branca do topo do layout](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57027/remover-barra-branca-do-topo-do-layout/57029?noredirect=1#comment117521_57029)

A princípio, quando vi a original eu pensei em sinalizar para fechar pois estava em inglês.

Eu entendo de PrestaShop por isso não julguei a questão como pobre de informações porque também o autor postou um recorte de screenshot para mostrar melhor o problema.

Isso é um problema referente a programação, então por quê marcar para fechar?

Outra coisa que levei em consideração é, há outros tópicos sobre como configurar uma IDE.
Quer dizer, configurar IDE não é assunto relacionado diretamente a programação, então tais tópicos deveriam ser fechados também.

Apenas para esclarecer, antes que venha alguém interpretar de forma distorcida, não estou dizendo que PrestaShop é uma IDE.. rrsssrs .. Foi apenas um exemplo.

Creio que quem vota, quem julga, deve conhecer do assunto em pauta antes de estar julgando.

Não sou contra "quem" julgou, pois não tem nada pessoal nisso, blz?
Só não concordo com o julgamento.

obs: não lembro no momento os outros topicos sobre ide.

Comment: Votei pra reabrir (e dei um +1 pra anular o -1). De fato a pergunta parece pobre de informações à primeira vista, mas você está certo quando diz que quem julga tem de conhecer do assunto para não tomar uma decisão leviana. Em tempo: *não estou afirmando* que quem votou pra fechar foi leviano, vai que eles entendem do assunto mas só tiveram uma interpretação diferente da sua... *Eu* não tenho como saber. De qualquer forma, estou partindo do princípio que, na dúvida, melhor deixar aberta do que fechar (principalmente se você diz que entende do assunto e não achou a pergunta ruim).

Answer (score 7):

O problema narrado na pergunta *parece* um problema de programação. Mas mesmo considerando que seja, a pergunta pode ser respondida? Eu acho que faltam dados. O melhor que dá para fazer é orientar o usuário sobre como diagnosticar o problema por conta própria, como você faz na sua resposta. A resposta não resolve o problema, como o AP [e você mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57027/remover-barra-branca-do-topo-do-layout/57029?noredirect=1#comment117582_57029) apontam nos comentários. E a culpa não é da resposta, a culpa é da pergunta, que não deixa claro qual é o problema (apenas o sintoma), nem oferece subsídios para que alguém do site possa diagnosticá-lo e corrigi-lo.

Por isso, independente de o motivo de fechamento estar correto ou não, não estou reabrindo essa pergunta por enquanto. A comunidade, é claro, pode discordar, e reabrir por conta própria. Seria legal também indicar ao AP como ele pode editar e complementar sua pergunta para torná-la respondível.

Comment: A questão é que eu tenho experiência com o assunto, e posso afirmar que é uma situação obscura. É realmente complicado para qulquer usuário ao menos saber o quê perguntar. Não é um tipo de pergunta que requer uma "solução absoluta", mas considero que seja válida porque é possível responder com algo útil apontando a provável causa do problema, o que responde a dúvida de como investigar o caso e então encontrar uma solução específica.

Comment: Mas agora estou em dúvida. Esse tipo de situação é aceita? Pois é um caso ambíguo onde a questão parece carecer de informações, mas não é culpa do autor, e sim devido a situação ser "obscura". Normalmente alguém experiente não faria esse tipo de pergunta porque saberia como diganosticar e obviamente encontraria o problema e a solução facilmente. Mas para quem não tem experiência com a plataforma, fica confuso, não sabe nem o que ou como perguntar. Mas para mim a pergunta está bem clara. É uma situação comum, recorrente dentre os usuários PrestaShop e outras plataformas com mecanismos CMS.

Comment: Vou pensar mais, talvez eu mude de ideia. Se é algo comum, pelo qual muitos novatos dessa plataforma passam, pode ser uma pergunta útil. Sei que tem casos igualmente obscuros para o usuário (como a página em branco de vários frameworks de PHP, ligado às configurações de debug da linguagem). Por outro lado, fiz agora uma busca no Google sobre o assunto, e as principais soluções envolvem alterações de CSS, e alterações diferentes em cada caso relatado. E na pergunta aqui não dá nem pra ter certeza de que o AP saiba como mexer no CSS...

Answer (score 5):

Minha opinião não é muito diferente da do bfavaretto... Mas tem algumas coisas a mais

Eu concordo com o Daniel Omine que a suspensão por estar fora de escopo não faz sentido. Mas concordo com o bfavaretto sobre a ausência de dados para que uma resposta possa ser dada. A maior evidência disso é que, mesmo com a experiência do Daniel Omine, uma resposta *ainda* não consegue ser dada. Se alguém com conhecimento sobre o tema não consegue responder à uma pergunta, é porque a pergunta precisa ser melhorada.

Concordo com os comentários do Daniel Omine (na resposta do bfavaretto aqui) que é complicado para um iniciante conseguir identificar exatamente *o que* está acontecendo de errado. E isso gera perguntas desse tipo. E nessas horas acho que pessoas com experiência no assunto se tornam extremamente valiosas.

A melhor coisa a se fazer pelo AP, e pela pergunta, é ajudá-lo a identificar e apresentar o problema de maneira clara. A edição que o Daniel Omine fez melhorou alguns aspectos, mas *talvez* ela ainda possa melhorar ainda mais a pergunta (isso é só uma conjectura). Além disso, pode ser possível fazer com que o AP forneça mais detalhes nos comentários que podem ser adicionados à pergunta.

Pode ser tarde demais, dado o tempo, mas acho que vale a pena tentar conseguir mais informações do AP. Acho que o Daniel Omine é plenamente capaz de saber quais perguntas fazer para apresentar melhor o problema.

Não tenho dúvidas de que esse *problema* é perfeitamente cabível no site, mas tenho ressalvas quanto à forma como ele foi perguntado.

Comment: Exato, escreveu muito bem!

Mas posso afirmar que não está faltando nada na pergunta. 
Normalmente, usuários PrestaShop peguntam no forum particular do PrestaShop, onde obtem-se respostas e suporte mais conciso. Ele deve ter peguntado aqui para ver onde conseguirá resposta mais rápida.

Comment: @DanielOmine Pois é, nada contra a pergunta ser feita. Mas sua resposta soa bastante incerta - cheia de "pode ser isso" e "tente isso" - o que é sinal de que o problema não está muito bem explicado. Não há nada que o AP poderia fornecer que te ajudaria a identificar exatamente o que está errado? Um trecho de HTML/CSS? O nome e versão do tema? Alguma configuração do PrestaShop?

Comment: Um problema aqui no SO é que esperamos uma resposta exata para as perguntas. Porém, há diversos casos como esse onde uma resposta "exata" necessita de um diagnóstico. O que postei é meramente um diagnóstico inicial e não uma resposta "exata".
Uma resposta mais exata necessita de um feedback do autor da pergunta. Então voltamos a questão da pergunta incompleta. E caímos nesse meu argumento onde eu aponto que realmente não há como o AP informar mais detalhes pois ele está num ponto de limitação.

Comment: Seria interessante se tivesse uma opção de marcar uma pergunta para uma fila de diagnósticos. Essa "fila de diagnostico" seria para questões válidas como essa que, para chegar a uma solução, necessitam de um diagnóstico. Não sei se isso já foi discutido ou se seria permitido, bom ou ruim.. enfim.

Comment: @DanielOmine *Em teoria* o fechamento serve pra isso. Na teoria, o destino de grande parte das perguntas fechadas é a reabertura, depois de terem seus problemas consertados pela comunidade ou a AP. Minha opinião é de que essa pergunta tem tudo pra ser reaberta, mas no momento alguém precisa ajudar o AP a dar mais detalhes. Mas não podemos fugir da "restrição" de esperar problemas com respostas exatas, isso atrapalharia o site.

Comment: O que reclamo é que o status de "fechamento" não se aplica apropriadamente para esse caso específico. Sugiro que poderia ter uma nova opção. Algo como "pergunta ambígua" ou "quarentena", onde ficariam perguntas desse tipo, que são "incompletas", mas não incompletas por falha do autor, mas por ser realmente limitada, carente de diagnóstico. Aliás, pensando bem, talvez a nova opção sugerida deixasse o SO mais complexo e confuso.. Precisa avaliar se mantém como está ou se podemos mexer nisso.

Comment: @DanielOmine Já tivemos alguns debates sobre uma tradução melhor para "fechamento" que passaria uma impressão menos definitiva... E o SOen tem uma fila específica só para lidar com reaberturas. É um problema complicado

Comment: Isso! Dá impressão de ser algo definitivo, o termo "fechamento".

Comment: @DanielOmine A alteração das traduções tá paralisada no momento, por um excelente motivo. Mais pra frente vai ser mais fácil envolver a comunidade e resolver essas coisas